# NDK Native Class not found Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I've been trying to figure out why I'm getting an error stating the method can't be found, but everything seems to be in order (at least the things that would cause this error).

My Android class:

```
package com.liamw.root.androididchanger;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DebugUserActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;
    TextView logcat;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("sqlite");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.debug);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        logcat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                runSQL("example.sqlite3", "SELECT Value FROM MyTable");
            }
        });

        /*try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c").waitFor();
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v long *:*");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    process.getInputStream()));
            while (true) {
                String nextLine = reader.readLine();

                logcat.setText(logcat.getText().toString() + "\n" + nextLine);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

    }

    public native void runSQL(String path, String query);

}
```

The native file (idchanger.c):

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <android/log.h>

#include <../sqlite3.c>
#include <../sqlite3.h>

#ifndef LOG_TAG
#define LOG_TAG "idchanger.c"
#endif

#define SQLITE_NDK_VFS_NAME "name"

#define LOGI(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOGD(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOGE(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))

void Java_com_liamw_root_androididchanger_DebugUserActivity_runSQL(JNIEnv * env,
        jobject this, jstring query, jstring path) {

    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    jboolean isCopy;
    const char * rQuery = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, query, &isCopy);
    const char * rPath = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, path, &isCopy);

    if (sqlite3_open_v2(rPath, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, SQLITE_NDK_VFS_NAME) == SQLITE_OK) {

        LOGI("Database opened OK");

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, rQuery, -1, &stmt, NULL)
                                        == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            LOGI("Table opened OK");

            int err;

            while ((err = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                LOGI("Value: %s\n\n", sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0));
            }

            if (err != SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                LOGE("Query failed: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            }

            LOGI("Finalise...");
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        }
        else
        {
            LOGE("Could't execute query: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }


    }
    else {
        LOGE("Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }

    LOGI("Close connection");
    sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

The error:

```
09-07 20:48:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(21193): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-07 20:48:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(21193): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.liamw.root.androididchanger.DebugUserActivity.runSQL:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
09-07 20:48:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at com.liamw.root.androididchanger.DebugUserActivity.runSQL(Native Method)
09-07 20:48:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at com.liamw.root.androididchanger.DebugUserActivity$1.onClick(DebugUserActivity.java:34)
09-07 20:48:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
09-07 20:48:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17362)
09-07 20:48:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-07 20:48:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-07 20:48:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-07 20:48:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
09-07 20:48:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 20:48:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-07 20:48:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
09-07 20:48:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
09-07 20:48:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Everything seems to be in order to me, but what is the error?

EDIT:

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

$(LOCAL_PATH)/../sqlite3.c:
    $(MAKE) -C $(@:%/sqlite3.c=%) sqlite3.c

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid
LOCAL_MODULE    := sqlite
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../sqlite3.c idchanger.c
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

EDIT2:

Aha! This is added to the logcat:

```
09-09 19:59:28.605: D/dalvikvm(9696): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libsqlite.so 0x40e46360, skipping init
```

Edit 3: I just noticed that on a test app I made, there are some lines in the logcat stating that it attempted to load the library, and then the ndk library file...

I don't see those lines here....

Comment: Find the part of the logcat where it succeeds (or fails) to load your native library.  Also make sure that your native library is current and not a stale build from yesterday, as is very easy to have happen.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I deleted the entire obj folder (or whatever the folder that contains the build is called). There appears to be no messages previous to that, however I'll take a closer look tomorrow.

Comment: If there's no previous message, then it never even *tries* to load your library.

Comment: Isn't there something wrong with line 32 on your DebugUserActivity class assuming you copy pasted that directly from your code? I mean that closing paranthesis and semi-colon.

Comment: Isn't causing the exception - but it seems you have reversed the path and query parameters from Java to C

Comment: Also, can you show us your Android.mk file?

Comment: @krsteeve ah, good catch there. That would've caused headaches down the line... Also, adding it now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the libsqlite.so has already existed in system/lib, which has higher priority than the libsqlite.so built in your project lib folder. so when you call `System.loadLibrary("sqlite");`, the system/lib/libsqlite.so will be loaded. You can rename your lib, like "mysqlite", and have a try again.

Answer (score 0):

add `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true`
in the `gradle.properties` to continue using the current NDK integration.